# Strange characters at the end of string

Tags: c, string

I want to fill a string with '_' so I have

```
while (i < length) {
  myWord[i] = 95;
  i++;
}
```

length is const int typed by user. but when i type `printf("%s",myWord);` it's output is '***_*___**#S' or '**__*_*_**#' or sometimes it's output is good.

Where is a problem? Thank you :)

Comment: The problem is that you're not _null terminating_ the myWord array.

Comment: Probably not null terminated.

Answer (score 2):

A String must end with a \0 char

```
while (i < length) {
  myWord[i] = 95;
  i++;
}
myWorkd[i] = 0;
```

Comment: +1. Or just initialize `myWord` with `\0` at the very beginning.

Comment: @user3388898: If you had used a string literal, it would be have been null-terminated by default.

Comment: @user3388898: your status suggests you have not yet read the [About page](http://stackoverflow.com/about). If you do so, you might find clicking "Accept" (the large greenish checkmark thingy) is preferred over a 'thank you'.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you forget to terminate your string with NUL (`\0`) character.

Answer (score 0):

Allowing the user to enter in the length of the string is prone to error. What if the user enters in 99999 and the length is actually 10? Boom. Undefined behavior.

If you had used a string literal, it would have been [automatically null-terminated by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11229646/2591612). `char` arrays are not automatically null-terminated.

> What happens if a string that isn't null-terminated gets passed to
>   `strlen()`? Undefined Behavior. `strlen()`, when given such a beast,
>   will keep searching memory until it a) finds a null character; or b)
>   hits an address that causes a memory protection fault of some sort (or
>   worse). strlen(), at least, is read-only; so it won't corrupt data.

http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?NonNullTerminatedString

Since you don't know the size of the array, a safer alternative would be to figure it out yourself:

```
int elements_in_x = sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]);
```

For the specific case of char, since `sizeof(char) == 1`, `sizeof(x)` will yield the same result.

If you only have a pointer to an array, then there's no way to find the number of elements in the pointed-to array. You have to keep track of that yourself. For example, given:

```
char x[10];
char* pointer_to_x = x;
```

there is no way to tell from just `pointer_to_x` that it points to an array of 10 elements. You have to keep track of that information yourself.