# Trying to randomly generate a string in order to get a conditional to execute

Tags: c, random, c-strings

Seems that strings in C are my weak point, need your guys' help again.  I should have included this in my first one, so I apologize about that.

So I have this function that I got working correctly, it fills a string with random chars from the set {r, e, s, e, t} and returns it:

```
char *inputString()
{
    static char string[6];
    const char *digits = "reset";
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
    {
        string[i] = digits[ rand() % 4 + 0 ];
    }

    return string;
}
```

So the char at string[5] is '\0', correct? And string[1] through string[4] are random combinations of the other characters (r, e, s, e, t).

Now, I have another function that calls this one.  These purpose of it is trying to get the printf statement to execute:

```
other_fxn() 
{
  char *s;

  while (1) 
  { 
    s = inputString();
    if (s[0] == 'r'&& s[1] == 'e' && s[2] == 's' && s[3] == 'e' && s[4] == 's'
        && s[5] == '\0') 
    {
      printf('worked!\n');
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

main:

```
{
   srand(time(NULL));
   other_fxn();
}
```

It compiles fine but the loop runs forever, with the if statement never executing. Can somebody help me out why it won't execute.  Thanks once again.

Comment: Don't you want to put `s = inputString();` within the loop?

Comment: yes, sorry I printed it wrong here the first time. Its inside the loop.

Comment: You never actually assign string[5] = '\0'. So the c-string you return in from input_string may not be null terminated. This may cause your infinite loop behavior as well.

Comment: `random chars from the set {r, e, s, e, t}` : It does not include `t` because `rand() % 4 + 0`

Comment: @TimothyMurphy `string` is `static`. So It is initialized to `0`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Ahh, but it's always better practice anyways.

Comment: If you fix your broken printf statement and add your missing headers, the code [works as expected](https://ideone.com/B5EWRq).

Comment: @KerrekSB I think you should post that as the answer since it's the only one that really answers the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  while (1) 
  {    
  s = inputString();
    if (s[0] == 'r'&& s[1] == 'e' && s[2] == 's' && s[3] == 'e' && s[4] == 't'
        && s[5] == '\0') 
    {
      printf('worked!\n');
      break;
    }

  }
```

First of all, in your example you are looking for word "reses".
And you just don't change a string inside the loop. So you will get out of the loop only if random string is reset after the initial generation. I don't know why do you need this, but code above will get out of the loop. Maybe not so soon, but it will.

Also, what is this one:

```
string[i] = digits[ rand() % 4 + 0 ];
```

Why `+ 0?` And why `% 4`, not `% 5`?

Better go with this:

```
char *inputString()
{
    static char string[6];
    const char *digits = "reset";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
    {
        string[i] = digits[ rand() % 5];
    }
    return string;
}
```

And try using debugger, it really helps.

Comment: sorry the function was supposed to be inside the loop, posted it wrong the first time

Comment: Isn't string [5] already '\0' anyways? when I declared it: string[6] I thought that meant null byte was at string[5] with indexes 0 -4 for characters

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but aren't `static` variables always initialised to zero due to their being in the `data` section? If so, `string[5] = '\0';` is redundant as it is already 0

Comment: @Levi
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229477/are-all-char-arrays-automatically-null-terminated

Comment: @Levi and also this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414215/initial-value-of-int-array-in-c
And to make it clear - yes, you are right, static makes it initialized.

Answer (score 1):

You are only running the `inputString` function once, so you will only ever receive one string. This can be fixed by moving the function call to the `while (1)` loop:

```
while (1) 
{ 
  s = inputString();
  if (s[0] == 'r'&& s[1] == 'e' && s[2] == 's' && s[3] == 'e' && s[4] == 's'
    && s[5] == '\0') 
    {
      printf('worked!\n');
      break;
    }
}
```

Also, to make your code slightly cleaner, you can use C's `strcmp` function to compare the string, rather than checking each individual character:

```
#include <string.h>

while (1) 
{ 
  s = inputString();
  if (strcmp(s, "reset") == 0) 
    {
      printf('worked!\n');
      break;
    }
}
```

Adding on to what @Pavel said about your random character selection, to make it a bit more reusable, you can use `sizeof` instead of a hard-coded `5`:

```
string[i] = digits[ rand() % (sizeof(string) - 1)]; // Also removed extraneous 0
```

Comment: sorry the function was supposed to be inside the loop, posted it wrong the first time

Answer (score -1):

I have two changes for you:
You can make sure string[5] is 0. (It should already be because it's static)

```
char *inputString()
{
    static char string[6];
    const char *digits = "reset";
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
    {
        string[i] = digits[ rand() % 4 + 0 ];
    }
    string[5] = '\0'; // null terminate your string.

    return string;
}
```

you can avoid doing while(1) by just putting the condition inside the while conditional check. and then perform the print after the while loop.

```
other_fxn() 
{
   char *s = inputString();

   while (s[0] != 'r' || s[1] != 'e' || s[2] != 's' || s[3] != 'e' || s[4] != 's' || s[5] != '\0') 
   { 
    s = inputString();
   }
   printf('worked!\n');
}
```