# i think C can't read my input.(I am still a beginner learning c)

Tags: c, input

so every time i run my code in c only the second name is displayed,but the first one is never here

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int  main(void)
{

char name[5];
printf("Enter your name:");
scanf("%s",name);
char secondname[6];
printf("enter your second name:\n");
scanf("%s",&secondname);
printf("hello %s\n",name);
printf("%s how old are you",secondname);


return 0;


//%d is for integersf
//%s is for strings



}
```

The output is usually like this:

```
enter your name:
john
enter your second name:
smith
hello hisham how old are you?
```

Comment: The code shown does not have any print statement for the second name. If that's not the problem then please show the exact run log - the exact input and output.

Comment: the code has been updated!

Comment: Can you please be clearer and more precise in your description? You say "only the second name is displayed,". But that's not what the output shows - there is something shown but it is not the second name that was entered. Can you please clarify?

Comment: but the secondname variable is the only one that gets printed this is the problem.

Comment: The program does work with the input `John Smith`. You are entering something else which overflows the tiny buffers, but it's not `John Smith`.

Comment: i understand what you mean one second

Comment: Make sure you put a closing bracket and add '&' to the scanf of second name.Alos give maybe more arrayval for char String just to be safe.

Comment: Are you getting that exact output from running the program or are  you typing it from memory?

Comment: The program does not output what you say, even after the edit.

Comment: thank you @WeatherVane , but what is the meaning of buffer overflow.

Comment: Please see [Explanation of C buffer overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52003862/explanation-of-c-buffer-overflow). It is focused on `gets()` but the same applies to `scanf("%s", name)`. But, you changed the input given to the original code, which was stated to output `hello hisham`. This input does exactly what is expected, with `hello john` and `smith how old are you` output on separate lines.

Comment: This Q&A,is a mess now.  You should delete it, ask again without the errors and misleading test conditions.  It could then be closed as a dupe.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%s",&name);`
you didnt use & for the first input